# Making new struct point to data from old struct without old struct deleting it

Tags: c++, pointers, ffmpeg, libav

Here's how I decode videos in ffmpeg:

```
AVFrame* avFrame;
avFrame = av_frame_alloc();
int receiveFrameResult = avcodec_receive_frame(avCodecContext, avFrame);
```

Now my `AVFrame` struct has video data in its `uint8_t * data` field.

I want to create my own struct `myNewStruct` which holds the data that `AVFrame` has in `uint8_t * data[]`.

The problem is that I don't want to waste CPU time by copying value by value from `avFrame->data` to `myNewStruct->buffer`.

I also can't simply copy the data like this:

```
myNewStruct.buffer[i] = new uint8_t;
myNewStruct.buffer[i] = avFrame->data[i];
```

because when `avFrame` gets destructed, it deletes the allocated data for `data`. I also can't avoid deleting `avFrame` because it contains other unuseful fields that I don't want in `myNewStruct`.

How should I make `myNewStruct->buffer` point to the same data as `avFrame->data` points, but without worrying if `avFrame` is going to delete it?

**UPDATE:**

`AVFrame` is from ffmpeg so I don't have any control of its contents, therefore I cannot make its pointers of type `shared_ptr`

Comment: What about using a `std::shared_ptr`, instead of raw pointers?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I'm aware of shared_ptr benefits, but I don't control AvFrame, therefore I need to deal with the fact that it uses raw pointers. That being said, I also can't create a shared_ptr fo AvFrame, because I really need to throw it away almost immediately after its creation, because I need to create a new struct which contains some of its members (why? because I also want to deal with frames decoded from other decoders, so I need a common struct for all of them)

Comment: Hmm, well. Looks like your chances are low to get away without copies then. You probably should [edit] your question to make it clear that you don't have control over these structures used.

Comment: Your `myNewStruct` could just hold the AVFrame itself maybe?

Comment: @Moeren if that's the only possibility, I'll have to do it. But I realy wanted to get rid of anything ffmpeg-related and create a struct that is unaware of any decoder, so I don't need to include android decoder sources into the desktop app, for example

Comment: Could you assign the pointer to myStruct and then assign data in AVFrame to null? No idea if that feasible.

Comment: You could try just stealing the pointers - `myNewStruct.buffer[i] = avFrame->data[i]; avFrame->data[i] = 0;` - but whether that's supported is another matter.

Comment: @molbdnilo you and john had the same idea, but what you mean supported?

Comment: Unrelated: `myNewStruct.buffer[i] = new uint8_t;` and then immediately overwriting it is a memory leak. (`new` is not used to create pointers.)

Comment: @molbdnilo thanks I'll fix it (unrelated)

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs You need to investigate whether that is something you're allowed to do or if something might break.

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs According to my very brief reading of the documentation the data is actually held in something called an AVBuffer, and that is reference counted. So maybe you should be looking into that.

Comment: @john where did you find this information? I want to learn what a reference count means

Comment: Referencing counting is a technique where an object keeps track of how many 'references' have been made to is, and only gets freed when that count reaches zero. Reference in this context isn't the same as a C++ reference, but just means any way that one object can refer to another. Reference counting is a very well known technique and quite easy to implement in C++. I'm sure you can google it if you want to know more.

Comment: I'm getting my info from [here](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/2.8/group__lavu__buffer.html) but I'm no expert on this API. But I think the point is that the AVFrame will be holding a reference to an AVBuffer (so it's reference count will be 1) if you also make a reference to the same buffer then it's reference count will increase to 2. When the AVFrame is destroyed the buffers reference count will go back to 1 again but the buffer won't be deleted because the reference count is still more than zero. Only when you drop you reference will the count go down to zero and the buffer be freed.